# I try retrofit with Rapid API : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to use retrofit with rapid api and I got warning I'm new in retrofit pls Help me
I try this on postman and it work but when I try in retrofit it show this warning

**"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"**

my data Looklike this :

```
[
{
    "kanji": {
        "character": "進",
        "stroke": 11
    },
    "radical": {
        "character": "⻌",
        "stroke": 3,
        "order": 72
    }
},
{
    "kanji": {
        "character": "身",
        "stroke": 7
    },
    "radical": {
        "character": "⾝",
        "stroke": 7,
        "order": 194
    }
},
{
    "kanji": {
        "character": "神",
        "stroke": 9
    },
    "radical": {
        "character": "⺭",
        "stroke": 4,
        "order": 121
    }
},
{
    "kanji": {
        "character": "臣",
        "stroke": 7
    },
    "radical": {
        "character": "⾂",
        "stroke": 6,
        "order": 203
    }
}
]
```

data class :

```
data class PojoKanjiItem(
val kanji: Kanji,
val radical: Radical
)
```

--

```
data class Kanji(
    val character: String,
    val stroke: Int
)
```

--

```
data class Radical(
    val character: String,
    val order: Int,
    val stroke: Int
)
```

api service :

```
interface RapidService {
    @Headers("rapidapi-key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    @GET("on={kanji}")
    suspend fun getKanji(@Path("kanji")kanji:String): Response<List<PojoKanjiItem>>
}
```

this is my code :

```
//try　Rapid
val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).baseUrl("https://app.kanjialive.com/api/public/search/advanced/")
    .build()
val rapidService = retrofit.create(RapidService::class.java)

lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    val response = rapidService.getKanji("shin")
    Log.i("RAPID",response.body().toString())
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it means that you are not getting the data you say you are getting. It doesn't start with `[` but with `"` probably

Comment: should i use @Query instead this is link https://kanjialive-api.p.rapidapi.com/api/public/search/advanced/?on=shin&rapidapi-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx